# Blockwise Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

There exists a convenient formula for computing the inverse of a block matrix consisting of 4 matrices $\mathbf{A, B, C, D}$

$ \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}\end{bmatrix} ^{-1}$

the inverse can be written as a function of $A^{-1}$ and $(A-B D^{-1}C)^{-1}$ ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion))

$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} & -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1} \\ -(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} & (\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$

I wonder if a similar formula exists for the pseudo-inverse of non-invertible block matrices.

Comment: Someone might check whether or not the formula given above, with all ${}^{-1}$s replaced with $^+$s, satisfies the conditions for the MP pseudoinverse. That someone will not be me...

Comment: Ha, I tried that on an example. Certainly doesn't work in general. (but I'll try again just in case I made a mistake)

Comment: The biggest obstacle is due to the fact that, as you found out,  pseudoinverses are not substitutes for the regular inverses. Please check the definition on elsewhere, there is no place that says $AA^\dagger = I$. Therefore, the woodbury-sherman-morrison does not roll out directly from such a construction.

Comment: @percusse: the formula given above is quite a different beast from SMW...

Comment: @J.M. : If you take the Schur complement of a matrix and invert the three block you will get this formula. How is it different from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison%E2%80%93Woodbury_formula)?

Comment: @percusse: I don't use the term "Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury" to name this formula for a partitioned inverse (but I do agree that they're related). Do you?

Comment: No, I don't but I think the OP will google it anyway and end up in that page ;) (I was a little bit cynical I agree, I shouldn't do that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the fabulous search engine netted me quite a lot of references on the pseudoinverses of partitioned matrices. [Miao's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795%2891%2990351-V) gives a pretty general formula, [Cline's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0112050) concentrates on column-partitioned matrices $\mathbf A=[\mathbf U\quad\mathbf V]$, [Rohde's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0113070) handles the pseudoinverse of a partitioned Hermitian matrix, [Hall and Hartwig's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0130056) give formulae for column-partitioned matrices and row-partitioned matrices $\mathbf A=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf U\\\mathbf V\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$, and [this paper by Hartwig](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0131003) gives an expression for the pseudoinverse of a bordered matrix, $\mathbf A=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf B&\mathbf u\\\mathbf v^T&c\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$.

As you can probably tell from the number of papers that needed to treat special cases (depending usually on the ranks of the blocks and such), the expression for the pseudoinverse of a block matrix can be quite complicated. I will not try to reproduce those formulae here, and instead ask you to consult those papers and their references.

Comment: Thank you, I will read those papers.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a late answer, but I had been searching for this for a while as well and finally found something I thought was more satisfying. There is a paper "[The Moore-Penrose inverse of a partitioned matrix $M  = \begin{bmatrix} A & D \\\  B & C \end{bmatrix} $](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379575901184)" in Linear Algebra and its Applications by Hung & Markham from 1975. They give a more general formula for the pseudoinverse of a matrix, and then give a corollary with necessary and sufficient conditions that cause the formula to reduce to one that looks familiar. I'll record it here for progeny, but take a look at the paper.

**Theorem** Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}A&D\\\ B&C\end{bmatrix}$. Then

$M^{+} = \begin{bmatrix}K^{+}(A^{*}-EF) & K^{+}(B^{*}-EH)\\\ F & H\end{bmatrix}$,

where

$
\begin{align*}
K &= A^{*}A + B^{*}B\\\\
E &= A^{*}D + B^{*}C\\\\
R &= D - AK^{+}E\\\\
S &= C - BK^{+}E\\\\
L &= R^{*}R+S^{*}S\\\\
T &= K^{+}E(I-L^{+}L)\\\\
F &= L^{+}R^{*}+(I - L^{+}L)(I+T^{*}T)^{-1}(K^{+}E)^{*}K^{+}(A^{*}-EL^{+}R^{*})\\\\
H &= L^{+}S^{*}+(I-L^{+}L)(I+T^{*}T)^{-1}(K^{+}E)^{*}K^{+}(B^{*}-EL^{+}S^{*})
\end{align*}
$

**Corollary** $M^{+} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A^{+}+A^{+}DHBA^{+} & -A^{+}DH\\\\
-HBA^{+} & H
\end{bmatrix}
$

if and only if

$\begin{align*}
Null(A) &\subset Null(B)\\\\
Null(A^{*}) &\subset Null(D^{*})\\\\
Null(H) &\subset Null(B^{*})\\\\
Null(H^{+}) &\subset Null(D)\\\\
H &= (C-BA^{+}D)^{+}.\\\\
\end{align*}$