# Inverse of block triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, pseudoinverse, block-matrices

How to find the pseudo-inverse of the following block lower triangular matrix?
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ 
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $A$ is a $n\times n$ lower triangular matrix, $d$ is a scalar and $c$ is a $1\times n$ vector. Suppose that I know inverse of $A$ a priori.

Comment: If $A$ is assumed to be invertible and $d$ is non-zero, then the pseudo-inverse is just its inverse. You can refer to this article "SINGULAR VALUE DECOMPOSITION AND THE MOORE-PENROSE INVERSE OF BORDERED MATRICES by ROBERT E. HARTWIG" for some pseudo-inverse formulas of such matrices.

Comment: @La Rias: great reference. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2100398?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: [A related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62249)