# Expand Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of two sum of symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I was studying a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse matrix and found out below theorem in https://www.kybernetika.cz/content/1979/5/341/paper.pdf.

If $V$ is $n \times n $ symmetrical matrix and if $X$ is an arbitrary $n \times q$ real matrix, then
\begin{align}
(V+XX^T)^+ = V^+ - V^+X(I+X^TV^+X)^{-1}X^TV^+ + (X_\perp^+)^TX_\perp^+, \\
where \;\; X_\perp = (I-VV^+)X.
\end{align}

What if $X$ is an arbitrary $n \times 1$ real vector? Actually, I already calculate those
term with R and it turns out when $X$ is a vector, that theorem went wrong. But I am not sure about my result.

Does theorem holds when X is an arbitrary $n\times 1$ vector?

or does not?

If not, how could I expand $(V+XX^T)^+$ when $V :n \times n $ symmetrical matrix and $X : n\times 1$ vector?

I also attach my R studio result image[image: R studio code]

Comment: @user1551 I also thought same as you, but as you can see in my R studio result image, they don't match.

Comment: Oh, no, the cross terms are missing in (10). Formula (8) is correct, though.

Comment: @user1551 what do the cross terms are missing in (10) mean??

Comment: Let $P=VV^+$. It is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $V$. We can decompose $XX^T$ into the sum $PXX^TP+PXX^T(I-P)+(I-P)XX^T+(I-P)XX^T(I-P)$ (where $(I-P)XX^T(I-P)$ can also be written as $X_\perp X_\perp^T$). Apparently, the authors have mistaken $XX^T$ as $PXX^TP+(I-P)XX^T(I-P)$.

Comment: @user1551 It takes time though, I understand what you mean. But I'm now confused that how to expand correctly $(V+XX^T)^+$. Could you explain about that?

Comment: This isn't easy. You may take a look at [the papers mentioned by J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62259) to see if there are any useful formulae.